# Was "Quarantine Hair" hat designed to be gender-inclusive?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, gender

The Quarantine Hair hat is quite clever but I paused: is this hat gender-inclusive? I happen to have short hair in my profile photo (I identify as she/her), but the hair-hat does seem slanted toward masculine.

Realized this isn't racially inclusive either. The image below is what we suggest messy hair looks like for the majority of the Stack Overflow community.

[image: messy and overgrown short black hair with a bird's nest]

---

Comment: I think defining short hair as "masculine" is itself a failure to be "gender-inclusive". Further, I think that if we over-analyze each hat, Winter Bash becomes a lot less fun, if not downright impossible, and I think that would be a great loss. If you don't like the way the hat fits, you don't have to wear it. There are plenty more to choose from!

Comment: Bald, short, long. Men, women, non-binary. It's true any combination of these is possible. Yet why wasn't the hat designed as a messy bun or ponytail?

Comment: Of course, I can't say for sure, because I didn't design it. But if I *were* going to design a "hair" hat, I wouldn't use those hair styles because they are harder to depict simply (requiring multiple dimensions/perspectives) and would result in a larger "hat" that wouldn't integrate as well with users' avatars. Maybe that's just a failure of my imagination and/or artistic skills, though. I don't know.

Comment: It's not easy to raise the issue. I receive replies and comments on SO that default to he/him/sir. It stings. I tell myself the likely explanation is the speaker identified that way. Still, I can't recall seeing that mistake go the other way. So yes, I doubt myself and wonder if I'm being oversensitive, but evidence suggests it's possible this is unconscious bias.

Comment: @stealththeninja: Part of the problem is some parts of the world use a nearly 100 years old version of English (due to text books not being updated and general inertia).

Comment: It is indeed a tricky problem, and probably not one that we should be discussing in comments underneath a question where it is only tangentially related, but... it's important to assume good intent, here as everywhere. First, rightly or wrongly, English is still taught traditionally in many places, where the masculine pronouns are also the generic/neutral ones. That's compounded by the fact that many SO users are not even native English speakers. Second, your user name is gender-neutral, so there's no reason why users should prefer feminine pronouns when addressing you if they don't know.

Comment: Regarding your update, where you note that the hat is not racially inclusive either: that basically concedes that it is impossible to have any hat in the hatbox that replicates human features, given the inherent diversity of the human race. Do you think that is reasonable? Should hats be limited to merely abstract objects? I'm not sure that is a positive development. I also question your claim that the hat suggests what the majority of the SO community looks like. I doubt the majority of the community plays balalaika, either. Or has a mask with an SE logo.

Comment: @CodyGray I picked a neutral name intentionally to not be penalized for my gender. I used a neutral avatar for a long time for the same reason. I appreciate your "good intent" reminder. I don't think it was created to be exclusive. But imagine the excitement to preview a new "Quarantine Hair" hat (again, hilarious), and I saw (in context) what could reasonably be matched to a cis-white male. That's not how I identify, and it felt implicitly biased.

Comment: FWIW, I perceive this hair as quite girly. But I guess some things are in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: "that basically concedes that it is impossible to have any hat in the hatbox that replicates human features" Not necessarily, it feels like I'm perceived as making this difficult. Some hats are pure function, others occupational. Somehow I think iconic hair like "Bob Ross" or "Aubrey Hepburn" could be received well, probably because they represent a specific individual.

Comment: If you really wanna push it, don't forget to feel offended by how it's black when lots of people have other hair colors. Honestly, it's a hat. Think of it as a wig. Doesn't have to be an accurate representation of anything - anyone can wear it, regardless of any individual factors you throw at it. Lots of other hats don't accurately represent everyone in the population, in part because they aren't meant to. They're a fun novelty you display on your profile pic for a few weeks, and then move on with your life. Also, the hats are gonna be gone soon anyway - tomorrow, IIRC.

Comment: @Zoe afro hair came to mind right after I made my "bun and ponytail" comment. This discussion has challenged me, too.

Comment: But why? It's not meant to represent two anyone is. If SO had a character generator, I'd understand your concern, but literally no one is going to look at the hat and think, "Oh, your hair looks like that?". The hat doesn't "represent" me either (in length, color, or messiness), but it makes 0 difference. It's temporary, I don't have to wear it if I don't want to (though the reason I don't is because of the angle), and literally none of the hats are meant to represent people. Also a bit hypocritical that you only mention the hair, but not

Comment: [the first hat in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357917/332043) - that hand, if you look at this from an overthought perspective that focuses on representation rather than fun, doesn't represent everyone. Edward doesn't either, nor does Bouncer. It's a hat, not an exact representation of real-life.

Comment: Also, if someone had designed it as a ponytail instead, someone else would've complained that it wasn't inclusive to some other group of people. There's no way to win if you overthink inclusivity so hard that you wanna add hundreds of versions of each hat to accurately represent the population (which isn't the intent - again, it's a hat event, not a character generator)

Comment: @Zoe are you familiar with the "Draw a scientist" experiment where a majority of children drew men? That's what I'm poking at here. If the prompt I see here is "draw 'quarantine hair' for the SO community" and the outcome is short, black, wavy hair... I'm not asking for 100 variants, but can you see how I might wonder if implicit bias played a part in the creation?

Comment: [The one from 1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draw-a-Scientist_Test#Gender)? The one where no one drew anyone trans, non-binary, or entirely genderless? Where the results were interpreted on a binary scale, and none of them could possibly be genderless or raceless? It's perfectly possible that the results are wrong when they're based on what the researchers see rather than what the kids actually made. Y'know, it's perfectly possible the designer tried their best to draw short hair in a neutral as possible way, precisely to allow for different interpretations of the hat.

Comment: Implicit bias does exist, I'm not gonna argue with you on that, but dragging that into something that could be intentionally designed to be neutral is completely unnecessary. I also know (of) someone who's a cis female with hair like that, admittedly somewhat less messy last I checked. Looks and feels neutral to me, looks masculine to you, looks feminine to ead - I'd say it's designed as optimally as possible, all things considered. Different perceptions of the same thing are a big indicator of that.

Comment: Also, please never reference that garbage experiment again. Even [wikipedia includes:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draw-a-Scientist_Test#Methodological) "Several researchers have raised other methodological issues. Jarvis & Rennie (1995) thought that the use of drawings without words could represent an abstract idea the observer may be unable to comprehend. They suggested that children be asked to add sentences or annotate their drawings to improve interpretation." -- the only thing it's representative of is how the scientists perceived the drawings, not what the kids actually intended.

Comment: Seems 'gender-inclusive' enough to me. And you can opt out from Winter Bash if you don't like how hats are designed, what's the point of making a fuss about it?

Comment: You want a ponytail? As a man I have thin hair and ponytails aren't something I can do anymore. I'm offended!  (On a more serious note.... If we try to play the 'Im offended/this is non inclusive' card, there will ALWAYS be someone that can feel this way. Can we just let fun be fun, and not try to look for offense everywhere? (No my offense at the ponytail isn't serious .. if this needed saying)

Comment: Since this is venturing into an alternate universe.... might as well address age inclusivity also. I'm a senior citizen with grey hair so that color will never apply to me

Comment: @Zoe thanks for respectfully engaging the discussion, for pointing out the short-comings in the study. Can I offer a different analogy, [the history of the "flesh-color" band-aid](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2013/06/the-story-of-the-black-band-aid/276542/)? To paraphrase a quote: "Harry Webber, responsible for advertising between 1963 and 1968, said that the product's flesh color was "a non-issue" during his years promoting it."

Comment: As @CodyGray pointed out, my [System 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking,_Fast_and_Slow) knows women and non-binary can have short hair (my hair's not that short but I know a couple folk who sport this look well). But my System 1 didn't match the hat preview to me in my video calls, it quickly matched to two or three men. It matched a harmful, incorrect stereotype for what a software engineer looks like. In a community with a difficult but optimistic history engaging women and non-binary folk, this felt like a possible, accidental step back.

Answer (score 9):

> The Quarantine Hair hat is quite clever

Yeah, I agree. It is pretty awesome that the team was so thoughtful to include a hat that was close to real life events for a lot of people, had grim consequences, yet brought some light in these dark times.

> is this hat gender-inclusive?

The jury is still out on that. There was no prior art or experience what quarantine hair looked like so the team faced the challenge to come up with an image that communicated the message, appealed to enough users and was relatively easy to produce. Going by the several Zoom, Skype, Google Meet and webex meetings I've been in I would say that hair fits everyone.

> Realized this isn't racially inclusive either. The image below is what we suggest messy hair looks like for the majority of the Stack Overflow community.

It certainly is an artistic expression of messy hair. I'm sure there hasn't been done a ton of user research among diversity groups before the final design of this "Hair" went live. From that angle you could argue it might not leave much room to apply alternative explanations for shape and color.

I personally  think "Quarantine Hair" and the "Social Distancing" were fine attempts to bring some joy to dark times.

Going forward, it might be beneficial to have design criteria up-front that guarantees an image conveys all intended messages, including inclusiveness. Coming up with such criteria is hard but we have at least 11 months to do better. The [Suggestions for Winter Bash 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358936/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2021) is already open. Your ideas and suggestions to make this event even more awesome are welcome there. This 2020 bash comes to an end soon-ish.

Comment: "It certainly is an artistic expression of messy hair." Indeed! Thank you for capturing what was so good about this hat, and what we can do to improve going forward.

Answer (score -9):

While I still don't know the intent of the designer, *there's evidence the design may have striven for gender-inclusion*. To use a parallel example, in 2017, Paul Hunt contributed gender-inclusive representations to the Unicode emoji character set. From [this article](https://slate.com/human-interest/2017/06/paul-hunt-made-gender-inclusive-emoji-for-non-binary-individuals.html), look at the design evolution:

[image: Hunt's evolution of the gender-inclusive emoji design]

The hat design still appears masculine to me despite wearing shorter hair styles myself and knowing a few "non-masculine" folk who also wear this style. This could be implicit bias on my part, and I may not be alone. It turns out there's a common bias toward "masculine by default". From [a different article](https://www.wired.com/story/designing-first-genderless-emoji/):

> As Hunt learned from conducting online surveys, he says, "there's a tendency in our culture to view things as masculine by default." On the other hand, emoji explicitly meant to represent women and girls are overly gendered—doe-eyed, lipsticked, and hairstyled to the point of reading as feminine caricatures.

Comment: Hi Downvoters! Please feel welcome to let me know what you found “not useful” about this answer, or suggest how it might be improved.

Comment: Voting expresses agreement or disagreement with a post. It serves no purpose to leave comments that the target audience will never see. (The people who downvoted this post have already moved on.) If someone wanted to leave a comment, they could have done so.

Comment: @CodyGray is it a bug, then, that the hover text (title) for the downvote arrow is "This answer is not useful"?

Comment: Meta sites work a bit differently than the main Q&A sites. The Q&A engine was never really designed for discussion, but we abuse the engine to do discussion on Meta sites anyway, and it works adequately enough. I would love if the tooltip got changed, but I don't have the ability to do that. I will continue, however, to be a big advocate of people expressing their opinions through the least noisy approach possible: voting. It has other benefits, as well, including one vote per person (not necessarily the loudest person always "winning").

Comment: The frustrating part of this whole discussion and votes (still) is: did I not explain myself well? did I present an incorrect viewpoint? am I missing a better way of thinking about this? Many comments summed up to "You can't please everyone" and that wasn't my point. Not PC, not design-by-committee, but could the design be unintentionally harmful? Because yeah it harmed me, I'm sick of being assumed a man for participating here.

Comment: Your comment notified me, because I'm the only one to have commented here. I'm sorry, but I don't know what else you are looking for. I think your explanation is reasonable and clear, but that obviously cannot guarantee that others agree with you. "Could the design be unintentionally harmful?" Yes, theoretically, but the community evidently disagrees that it is. Again, as I've said before, I'm sorry that people assume you are a man for participating here. I think that is wrong and unfair.